# Should we use the sandbox for answers, too?

Tags: discussion, answers, sandbox

So, the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) is now up, and there's a decent amount of activity. I like what I'm seeing: good dialogue between users on the posted questions.

I'm suggesting that we use the sandbox for answers, too. I'd like input on one I'm working on, and I daresay others would like it, too. Should we use the sandbox for this?

I'd advise not voting on this question; please vote on the answers posted below.

Another suggestion of mine here would be to not downvote any answers. That way, we can gauge the support of each option better.

---

**Post-Christmas Update**

After being away for some time, I see that things have gotten quite interesting. Four people have done what I said not to do and have voted on the question, while three have done what I said not to do and downvoted an answer. Ah, well, I shouldn't tell people what to do, as this is an issue for the community, not me.

Adding in ArtofCode's vote, the winner appears to be the option of having a separate sandbox. I'll leave it up to ArtofCode to create it, as s/he created the original one. In the meantime, feel free to voice any and all objections on the matter. This case isn't closed quite yet, though it may have reached its resolution.

---

**Final Update**

[The Answer Sandbox has been created.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/sandbox-for-proposed-answers)

Comment: Options as I see them are all posted.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thanks.

Comment: I think upvoting and downvoting on all answers you think warrant it will lead to a clear consensus sooner than if we restrict to only upvotes.

Comment: @githubphagocyte and HDE - we still seem to be at a bit of an impasse, 4|3|-2 votes. Yes is out, it seems, but separate and no are pretty close.

Comment: @ArtOfCode what was important to me was getting a question sandbox up and running. As long as that is present and doesn't have answers in it to confuse things, I don't mind either way whether there's an answer sandbox or not.

Comment: If enough votes come in for an answer sandbox, then even if the votes saying no are in equal number, I think we'd need to see a reason for not having one, since people who don't want one don't need to use it.

Comment: Sharing some reasons may also affect the voting, if anyone has any strong evidence either way to share?

Comment: @HDE226868: Answer sandbox is posted and linked from the question sandbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to post three answers, each detailing one of the options as I see it. Community members, please vote on these to indicate your agreement or disagreement with each option.

This option has my vote, so add 1 to the total votes on this post.

---

## Option 3: Separate Sandbox

The current Sandbox should be left for questions alone, but a separate Sandbox should be set up for answers as they are equally deserving of feedback, but the two should be kept separate. Answers in the Question Sandbox should be deleted, and vice versa.

Comment: This option may complicate things, but I support it. That way, we can give different kinds of input in each sandbox.

Comment: This one has a vote from me. However, I'd also support Option 2 - Yes, as long as it would be made clear when a post is an answer.

Comment: That was my thinking, too.

Comment: If we do end up going this route, I see no reason to have them both featured posts - just the question sandbox (it will be used more), and link the answer sandbox from there.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I agree that the question sandbox should be the featured one. I see it as higher priority.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to post three answers, each detailing one of the options as I see it. Community members, please vote on these to indicate your agreement or disagreement with each option.

---

## Option 1: No. Period.

The Sandbox should never be used for answers as they are more easily changed on the main site without negative consequences such as closing. Answers posted in the Sandbox for feedback should be deleted.

Comment: I feel like the SE format is already pretty flexible for evaluation and improvement of answers.  The main driver for the improvement of questions before hand, in my opinion anyway, is to avoid excessive changes to a question after it is originally posted.  This creates problems in voting as well as wasting the time of people answering against the early iteration(s) of a question.  The same isn't necessary with answers.

Comment: Also volume is a concern...there are ALOT of answers around this joint.  I don't know that we would keep up with reviewing answers twice...

Comment: @James I definitely agree about the volume point... I don't know, I just think that having the **option** for an answer to be community-checked might result in a better site. People don't have to use it

Comment: when it comes to answers I am far less opinionated about the subject to be honest.  I think it is crucial for ensuring good questions are asked, when it comes to answers I don't believe it is not potentially useful, but I find it far less necessary, and would probably not utilize it myself.

Comment: I do think that such a sandbox would be useful because it might help remove any long strings of comments below answers that sometimes show up. Long discussions are definitely for chat, not on answers. They'll show up in the sandbox, but it may be better to have them there than cluttering up posts on the main site. This would be a boon for questions, too, of course.

Answer (score -5):

I'm going to post three answers, each detailing one of the options as I see it. Community members, please vote on these to indicate your agreement or disagreement with each option.

---

## Option 2: Yes. Period.

The Sandbox is valid place for answers as they are just as subject to bad feedback as questions and could be made better with community feedback in the Sandbox. Answers posted in the Sandbox should stay.