# Sandbox for Proposed Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, sandbox

## What is the Sandbox?

This ["Sandbox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) is a place where Worldbuilding.SE users can get feedback on prospective answers they are writing. This is useful because writing a clear and fully specified answer on the first try can be difficult. There is a much better chance of your answer being well received if you post it in the Sandbox first.

To post to the Sandbox scroll to the bottom of this page and click "Answer This Question". This Sandbox is intended for **answers only**; for posting questions please use the [Question Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)

Answers do not have to be in any particular format, but they should conform to the general guidelines indicated in the post about answers in the [Sandbox FAQ](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/640/2685). In particular, you can use sandbox notes to indicate your thoughts on your own answer, written like this: `[**Sandbox note:** I still need to do X]`

Please review answers here by commenting and voting. If you think an answer is ready for the main site, indicate this with a comment and upvote. When an answer gathers enough support, it will be posted to the relevant question.

**See the [Sandbox FAQ](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/639/2685) for more information on how to use the Sandbox.** This information was originally written for the Question Sandbox, but much of it is also applicable to answers. Additionally, there is an answer there detailing specifics for answer posts.

### The Sandbox works best if you sort posts by "active" (click [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/sandbox-for-proposed-answers?answertab=active) to do so).

Comment: Could we add [a link to sort by active](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/656/sandbox-for-proposed-answers?answertab=active)?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Done

Comment: [Discussion about the necessity of the Answer Sandbox.](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/do-we-still-want-the-answer-sandbox)