# Please revisit this timely on-hold question soon

Tags: discussion, support

My post [Can characterization contributed by actors (not the writer) have a significant effect in building a rich and enduring imagined world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/how-has-leonard-nimoys-method-character-development-contributed-to-imagined-w) has been put on hold.

My on-topic question is whether non-author (non written word or documented) collaborators can have a profound effect on realizing the richness and success (lasting impression) of an imagined world.

If you don't think so, that should be an Answer, not a "it's not so go, away and nobody else can say otherwise"

If I didn't state the thesis clearly enough, please someone help me to improve upon it.  I further specialized it to be a tribute to Nimoy, so, it is rather timely and I want it available for other answers ASAP. It's been 15 hours since I commented on the on-hold, and as I said I'm at a loss as to how to more acceptablably explain it or make the concept more understood.

Comment: Unrelated to the question per se, but I notice some people have a tendency to get cranky when someone calls Stack Exchange a "forum". :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind, and consult a thesaurs for a more specific term, fur future use.

Comment: Forums are for discussion. Stack Exchange is a network of question-and-answers sites. It might not seem like a major difference in some cases, but basically that difference is a large part of what allows SE to keep producing quality answers to specific questions, rather than long-winded discussions that touch on things often not even related to the original problem. Forums *also* have their place, but that's a different place.

Comment: It also means *a public meeting or lecture involving audience discussion* such as a college history class. It doesn't specify the symmetry of presenting/questioning or rules of decorum. A regularly scheduled business meeting can be "a forum for announcing my project idea", but excessive chitchat is squelched.  It's the heavy loading of *Internet Forum* and how they are often conducted that makes people think of that. But the same software could be used for tech-support and heavily moderated to stick to the point.

Comment: I agree it's a connotation/denotation issue, hense the thesaurus. It's a writer's responsiblity to be clearly undersandable to his audience.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I need to ponder this and revisit the question, but it seems that your actual *question* is:

> In what ways has his Method results (not conventional writing nor anything regarding the overt setting) contributed to the World Building of the projects?

That sounds to me like you aren't really looking for insight into *the process of worldbuilding* or seeking help with *a problem you encountered during worldbuilding* (which is what this site is about) but rather want to discuss *the impact of a specific person on a specific worldbuilding process*. The latter being something that few people outside of the circle of people involved are likely to be able to answer, and seems peripheral at best to the site's purpose of adding to the corpus of knowledge on the Internet on the site's topic. Hence likely why the question ended up being put on hold as not about worldbuilding.

Also, note that Stack Exchange deals quite poorly with timing-specific questions. (Even though it doesn't see a whole lot of use, there's even an annotation specifically for questions dealing with rapidly-changing events.) Sure, on a busy site a question is likely to get its fifteen minutes of fame and then see little further activity, but I have seen questions receive well-thought-out answers literally *years* after the question was originally posted.

Comment: That's similar to, how I reworded it; thanks for the allignment.  I'd been chewing on a Q idea about non-writing collaborative input, but pulled it out as a Q&A for one answer that I wanted to get down immediatly.

Comment: A Q&A post kind of impies that the poster is not looking for insight but sharing an existing insight. SE has that feature and prompts people to take advantage of it.  Although once out of the editor, there is no indication other than the same ID on the Q and first A which has the same timestamp but won't necessarily appear first when later viewed.

Comment: @jdlugosz Just because a question is self-answered doesn't necessarily mean it's good. The question still has to meet all the other quality standards on the site, including topicality. In fact, self-answers in particular are often judged more harshly by the community.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick rule of thumb, characters aren't part of worldbuilding, much less actors playing the characters.  As such, we're probably not the best place for paying tribute to Leonard Nimoy.  This is not because we dislike him.  As a group, I expect most of us are rather fond of his work, particularly as Spock.

If you're looking purely for a Nimoy related question, perhaps something like

> ### How would the world need to be different for the predominant (humanoid) race to have green blood?
>
> I want to create a a world where the inhabitants look essentially human but have green blood (like the Vulcans on Star Trek).  What would have to change to make this happen?  Would it be as simple as replacing iron in the blood with something like copper or gold?  Or would we need to make more changes for this to make sense?

You could always post in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/2113) if you wanted to try to tweak a question into proper shape.

It would be really difficult to come up with a question that more directly links the actual character of Leonard Nimoy or even his acting skills to actual worldbuilding.  It's a touching tribute but not really appropriate for this site.  We don't deal with casting decisions.  Our focus is on helping people design backgrounds for their stories that are logically (and sometimes scientifically) consistent.  By the time that people are on to casting (assuming they are writing a screenplay or play), our job is done.  It's up to them to provide ambiance, etc. that can be provided by good acting, lighting, and proper settings.

Perhaps you are correct in describing the thing that you want to discuss as world building, but it's not the kind of worldbuilding that we do here.  Your question simply doesn't fit.