# How to avoid changing the nature of a question in an edit?

Tags: discussion

I have a tendency to edit extra content into my questions and sometimes it changes the questions and it seems like it is sometimes unavoidable despite the fact that I have been on this site for a while. I felt like I should ask on Meta.

What are the best practices in editing that can stop you from changing the nature of your question and in consequence the validity?

Comment: Your best bet is to first post the question in the sandbox.  We can critique and evaluate the question there and get it in shape for posting.  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Answer (score 4):

If your edit invalidates existing answers then it is usually better to ask it as a new question, otherwise editing is generally fine.

If you think that a question might need refinement then post it in [the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) first.

Comment: The sandbox is for before a question is posted on the main site.

Comment: @DustinJackson yes, post it to the sandbox before asking it in the main site to avoid having it changed afterwards - or close it on the main site, post it to the sandbox, then open it again once it's been refined. Again it's best to avoid invalidating existing answers though.