# Should I edit this question, from another user?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question ["Preventing centaurs from invading China"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22204/preventing-centaurs-from-invading-china) *seems* to imply that the OP seeks for a solution which does not require having guards at a gate.

This also makes sense, otherwise it would completely pointless to ask the question in the first place, since the answer would be… have a gate with guards.

Every answer besides one takes this assumption. [The other one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/22759/222) is basically a "well, obviously use guards".

[The only answer with more than 1 upvote](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/22700/222) opens up as:

> The easiest solution would be manually guarded gates. Open them in
>   normal use, close them when centaurs are approaching. They don't
>   interfere with normal usage so the people of the north can use
>   carriages or ride horses.
>
> **But your question seems to strive for a technical solution.**

Can I just edit the question then, to make this explicit, since apparently it is to most, but it is not to someone? The alternative is to downvote and close it as "unclear", but I'd rather edit and upvote, since I believe this would improve the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, you shouldn't edit your assumption into the question.**

If you are curious about what the OP intended then comment on the question and *ask them what they intended*. If they confirm your suspicion, then ask them to update the question, but [not in a way that invalidates existing answers](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1881/3202).

I don't find the question unclear at all. It may be that the asker simply didn't think of that possibility, not that they wanted it excluded from possible answers. Many questions really do have an obvious answer.

We're outside the OP's box, it's why they are asking us to look inside.