# Is "Uses of phlebotinum" on-topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

My world has a variety of types of phlebotinum with well-defined properties and a number of pre-defined applications.

I am considering writing a question on the main site giving these properties and asking for additional plausible applications given the defined properties.

Would this be considered idea generation, or would this be an acceptable question?

Comment: As you can read on other discussions on meta, "idea generation" is a variant of "too broad". So if you can reduce the scope of the expected applications, and moreover, providing a criteria to explain on which basis you'll consider the best answer, you're good to go.

Comment: One way this could be on topic is if you gave a specific problem and the phlebotinum, then ask how that problem could best be solved using the phlebotinum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As proposed here, I think that your question would be off topic as either *idea generation* (*too broad*), or *primarily opinion-based*.

This is mostly because with such a question:

- there would be no way to judge how well answers actually answer the question
- the potential set of answers would be unbounded; there would always be "one more" possible answer that nobody has posted yet

If you can fix those problems, then your question should work. As [bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9685/bilbo-pingouin) said in a comment, reducing the scope of the expected applications and providing criteria based on which answers can be judged would probably be a good start.

It might not be a bad idea to post your question to [the question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/29) initially.