# How to improve my question before it's closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

A question I asked has 3 close votes, what should I change about it before it's closed?

The question is 
[Cargo of a supernatural smuggler](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23485/cargo-of-a-supernatural-smuggler)

Is removing the "Bonus question" enough to prevent it from being closed?

If not should I add other information about the settings or the question itself?

PS: I'm not sure this is an appropriate use of the meta section, sorry.

Comment: Your question is currently on a path to being put on hold as "too broad". This means that there are too many possible answers. I haven't looked at your specific question in detail, but generally speaking, you need to add some criteria or details to it to narrow the set of possible answers. Note that it isn't a major problem if your question is put on hold; that simply means that no (more) answers can be added *until the issues prompting closure are worked out*. If you edit your question during the "on hold" grace period, it will automatically enter the reopen review queue.

Comment: It's fine to ask this type of question on Meta. You may want to try our [question sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/635/29) or drop by in [chat].

Comment: If you look at the answers to the question - you can see that almost all of them are actually multiple answers. This is the core of the problem, there is no way to know a "best" answer so there is no way to rate them against each other and even people writing answers have no way to rate which of their ideas is the best so just put them all.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of the sandbox question.  Using the sandbox provides an *answer* to this question, but we evaluate duplicates at the question, not at the answer.  Either way, I'm glad you found the sandbox helpful, and please do feel free to ask about specific questions (or answers) on meta.  That's why we have those tags.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I suggested a "duplicate" to sand box, as the OP had originally the whole question quoted and was asking for feedback on how to improve the question, which is, IMHO, what sandbox is for. But yes, the question in itself isn't a duplicate...

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin oh, thanks -- I hadn't noticed the revision history.  That makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for preparing and improving questions. This is to avoid a spread of posts accross meta for people who want feedback on their questions.

But just a note, if your question gets another VTC (voted to close), it will be placed [on-hold](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). In that state it can still be edited, so it's not a race against time. If it is on-hold, any edit will appear as a request to reopen.

As for a specifics to your question, you have too many supernatural creatures to make your question answerable.

Comment: A non-locked question can always be edited. Editing an "on hold" question pushes it into the reopen review queue automatically; editing after the question transitions to "closed" doesn't do so automatically, but anyone [with 15 rep or more](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) can still flag the question with a custom reason and suggest it be reopened, and one of us moderators will look into it.