# What is the best way to "evolve" my existing question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34157/what-sort-of-problem-would-drive-a-near-omnipotent-civilization-to-seek-an-outs) last night and got a lot of great responses, and I'm interested in pivoting off of it to further develop the ideas for my "world." Should I therefore evolve and update my existing question? Or, if they can stand on their own, should I stick to asking new questions, even if they are related? Is there a way to link questions (on top of the obvious way of simply linking within)?

Also, there are many answers that I consider to be valuable input. Is it therefore suitable not to pick a "best" answer in that case since they are all quite valuable? Or, as I would do on any other SE site, should I always pick a response?

At the end of the day, I view this as a valuable resource for my work, and I value the contributors' attention and time. I want to be a good steward of both. I would greatly appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: There's no reason to fear having *more* good questions and answers.**

What you describe sounds like the perfect reason to ask another question. You've got a good question, it's garnered good answers, and you can "close the book" on those, so to say.

If you post a new question and link to last night's in the body of the question the link will also show up in the "Related" sidebar for that question. And the reverse link will show up in the tergeted question. (*I.e.* you need only link once, and both questions will show the other as "related.")

(I can't speak to this SE's culture around acceptance rates. I know on my main site there's no inference of disrespect when never accepting an answer, even if many serve you well.)

Answer (score 6):

Asking a series of questions is just fine.  I've done it too -- I asked a question, the answers to which prompted another question, the answers to which prompted *another* question.  Make sure each question contains enough information to stand on its own (people shouldn't have to review all the others as prerequisite for reading the new one), and feel free to link.

If you ask a question and realize you need to refine it in some way, *and doing so won't invalidate existing answers*, it's fine to edit.  Most often this happens when somebody asks a question in a comment and you add that information to the question.  *However*, it's bad form to change your question in a way that breaks existing answers; that's asking that people who already tried to help you go back and do extra work or risk having their answers downvoted as not addressing the (current) question in some way.  An edit that harms existing answers will likely be rolled back when noticed.

If, as you're writing a question, you realize it might need a little extra work but you're not sure how to refine it, consider trying it out in the [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/28).