# Would either of my two hypothetical questions about economic policies be a good fit for this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I asked two questions on Politics SE which ask about the economic implications of implementing hypothetical economic policies, but I'm told they're probably not a good fit for Politics SE because they're very hypothetical.

I'm wondering if either of these questions could be edited to make a good fit for Worldbuilding SE, and if so how they would need to be posed in order to fit here properly.

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/what-would-be-the-economic-implications-of-a-government-offering-to-invest-10-0

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10755/what-would-be-the-economic-impact-of-implementing-a-flat-profit-sharing-policy-a

Comment: I'd have to agree with @MichaelKjörling It's best if you propose this idea on the Sandbox to get some feedback before you post on the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've already had [some](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30200/would-wiping-out-all-debt-crash-the-economy) [questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22805/funding-government-by-only-printing-more-money) on financial politics, so this topic seems generally fine. I'd say its part of this bullet point on the [what to ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> • Effects of events or world elements, including biology, technology and magic, on specific aspects of that world's societies, cultures, and environment

---

On a first glance, I would say your [first question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/what-would-be-the-economic-implications-of-a-government-offering-to-invest-10-0) seems basically okay.

- You have a clear cut setting
- You provide examples to explain your ideas
- Your question is clear

But there are some things you might want to reconsider:

- Your **Question** section is multiple questions:

  - What would be the economic implications of a government offering to invest $10,000 in every citizen's professional venture?
  - What would be the economic pros/cons, and
  - would this be a potentially viable solution to improving an economy? If not, what are the flaws in the concept?

I would say the first one is good and could be asked in your context. However, *"What are pros/cons?"* is generally very broad, and *"Would it improve the economy?"* seems very broad and basically opinion-based to me (not really sure about the opinion-based thing, but this would be difficult to answer objectively I guess).

---

Your [second question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10755/what-would-be-the-economic-impact-of-implementing-a-flat-profit-sharing-policy-a) again is *very* broad. I think this one needs a more thorough definition before it is being answerable in reasonable length. Further, I do not think asking *"Has this exact solution been considered and debated?"* would be on-topic for worldbuilding in this context but I would be glad to be corrected by others.

---

That said, I'd like to say thank you for checking that your question fits the site, that is a good thing to do. Next time (or maybe this time as well) check out the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). There you can post your questions as answer and people will give feedback and help you to make it fit the site - and they do a really good job with that.

Comment: I agree that "has this been considered and debated in our real world?" is not a good fit for Worldbuilding, as that inherently is about the real world, not a fictional world.