# Correcting a wrong question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I recently asked a question which was [Where to hide my evil Overlord?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45680/where-to-hide-my-evil-overlord) and it got closed for being "primarily opinion-based", the reason being that there are many possible answers. However when I saw a tag-related question like [Why fill a dungeon with puzzles?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36446/why-fill-a-dungeon-with-puzzles), it seems to me that it also can be answered in many ways.

So what is wrong with my question ? I do not want this to repeat.

Comment: For completeness, here's previous discussion: [Meta Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41848/wrong-question).

Comment: King, you may want to check out these go-to resources for asking questions: [How to write the perfect question?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3624/6986) and [Risk Factors](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3206/6986).

Comment: @Frostfyre I see, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why did your question get closed?

Primarily Opinion-based (also known as POB) isn't about the fact that there are many possible answers, but it is about the fact, that there's no way to compare those answers (for us), except basing our judgement on subjective opinion. So basically, we can't upvote better answers objectively. Which is not suitable to the format.

Generally asking for the "best X" leads to having a question closed as POB. What is *best* for you might not be the *best* for me. Or the other way around.

Furthermore your question has the other disadvantage that we know too little about your world.

The usual way to correct it is to provide some kind of metrics on which we could compare answers. Assuming you provide sufficient details, the nearest place, cheapest, darkest, etc. might be something to start with. Note that the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) might help you refine a question, and the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat), might help you get some discussion about it.

<sub>I see that you created a [subchat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41848/wrong-question) for it, with the link provided by Frostfyre. However, you cannot "ping" users there (unless you are a moderator), so it might not be seen. Best way would be to join the general chat and ask there.</sub>

#### Why wasn't the other question closed?

Well it might be some closed-edge, but the focus of the question isn't: *the best*, but *why*. So only providing a single example would be sufficient. I agree that the OP could have provided some metrics to compare the answers though.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have a draft of my latest question, is it too opinion-based ? See the chat