# "Why should I depend on my minions?" Being closed

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

This is getting annoying .... instead of asking [the best place to hide](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3731/correcting-a-wrong-question), Im simply asking [why would a evil lord depend on his minions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45779/why-should-i-depend-on-my-minions). But I get a response like this, "This question demonstrates a rather complete lack of understanding of how any organized human activity takes place."

Should I put some sort of note or something ? *That this question is only about the magical world where the Overlord has **already** gone to sleep and has left things to his minions, and the other people are wondering why ?*

Comment: As the previous question, some discussion was done [on chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41848/wrong-question).

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Yes, I understood :)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin: I am going to 'experiment' a bit and see the questions that I can ask, because there are some good questions which are too broad(unfortunately). For example, my recent question (Can Dungeon Monsters work together?) was originally "Why do Dungeon Monsters work together?" , but that was obviously too broad.

Comment: I personally really like your minions question, and didn't understand why it was closed. This is a "soft" site, there's going to be some opinion in any answer.

Comment: @kuhl : Thanks ^_^  However, it seems like the majority of my questions are getting close votes. *shrugs*

Comment: I would cast a vote to reopen, had I the necessary reputation. That was a really good question.

Comment: @Renan : Thanks. I was getting really sad with all the close votes. Your reputation is higher than mines btw, and I was able to reopen it - so mebbe you can to ? Also, I'm doing this for all my questions lol (reopening them)

Comment: I think you can try reopening your own ones if you edit them. Casting reopen votes requires 3,000 rep.

Comment: @Renan It does, or you could bring it up in [chat] which only requires 20 rep. :-)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Could you help in reopening it? :)