# Call to Sandbox Duty

Tags: discussion, sandbox

The [sandbox questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/885) don’t do any good if the proposed questions don’t get any feedback.  I’ve referred people to this sandbox, and the idea is to get better posts. For that to work we need to **discuss** why a question is too broad or unclear, and help the OP edit it so that it can be posted as a good question.

But I see sandbox questions with no comments.  In particular a closed question I suggested putting here for advice on improving—nada.  With the influx of newcomers I think this is more important than ever.

So I’m posting this as a **call for more attention**.

Even if you’re not at the rep milestone for review tasks, how about doing a similar pre-view here?

There are tough things like figuring out why some questions are acceptable and others are too (whatever).  If it’s OK, at least not that so the OP can see that the Q migbt be accepted already.  Harder is tightening it up, but experienced members can at least grunt and wave in the right general direction?

Easy stuff:

- What are the right tags?
- Is the OP’s grammar and English of a high quality?
- Might this be a duplicate?  Or not a dup enough to close, but older questions can provide input and allow the OP to refer to them explicitly and carve out a more specialized niche or compare and contrast with the other posts.
- Is the OP missing something vital?  Being informed of the right term allows for effective searching on the subject, or a good general link can allow the OP to better research before asking, and ask a better question while using standard terms and linking to the reference material.
- Should the question be asked on a different SE?

No news is…
    No comments means all is OK? Or did anybody even read it?  A quick comment noting that these above checklist has been checked by someone would be good to note.

No time or interest to reply in detail? Just note the non-ok-ness at least, if nobody else has.

Comment: I totally agree with you here, as a user that mainly asks, I would love it if this became a better tool

Comment: If you are encouraging more people to use the sandbox (which is a good idea In my opinion.) should we take this opportunity to delete some of the older answers from the sandbox as currently it is full of people's questions that have already been asked on main site.

Comment: @Bellerephon yes: the sandbox instructions points out that if you see one you can flag it for moderator’s attention.  Edit it to replace the whole body with just a link to the post, and flag it so the mod deletes and clears the comments.

Comment: Related: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/sandbox-cleanup-2016-edition . @Bellerephon if you find questions in the sandbox that were asked but not deleted from the sandbox, please flag so we can delete them.  Thanks.

Comment: COD: Stack Exchange

Comment: Also: Check if the question might be put on hold or closed on main and then suggest how to avoid this, especially for POB/too broad/not completely worldbuilding/unclear questions.

Comment: And I absolutely agree. The only person who helped me often on the Sandbox was Secespitus: and having just one other user help won't eliminate all the problems in a potential question