# Getting More Sandbox Helpers

Tags: discussion, sandbox, users

Regarding this post:

> [Call to Sandbox Duty](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/call-to-sandbox-duty?rq=1)
>
> > I’ve referred people to this sandbox, and the idea is to get better posts. For that to work we need to discuss why a question is too broad or unclear, and help the OP edit it so that it can be posted as a good question.

This is a **great** post. I think JDługosz brings up an important point, but there's one thing wrong.

We still don't have that many people in the Sandbox. (This is just my opinion.)

We need more people to help comment on potential questions on the Sandbox.

How do we attract more users not only to use the Sandbox (made easy by linking to it in comments) but how to get users to **help each other with their potential questions?**

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a serious problem with the sandbox. 
Personally, I go there from time to time but maybe not often enough.

My experience:

- Every time I go there, it seems like the posts already attracted
  plenty of comments.
- When I do post a comment, I find myself answering the question rather than giving feedback. That is not the purpose of the sandbox but I cannot resist.
- Questions in the sandbox tend to be much longer than the average question on main. I know that this is because the questions are not fully formed yet but it makes judging them more complicated.

Comment: Are there any ways to attract more feedback from different users?

Comment: @Anonymous It would be very hard. Activity on Meta is much lower than on the main site. For example, I asked a question the other day, only 5 people interacted including myself. I only have the opinion of 4 different people so I still have no idea what the community thinks about the issue.

Comment: Also, seeing that one question in the sandbox is already being managed by other users makes other people less likely to intervene. Especially if they seems to be comfortable with the topic.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you judge whether someone who is interacting with a draft seems to be comfortable with the topic?

Comment: @Secespitus with the number and lenght of the comments. Probably not the best method. Similar to this I guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect

Comment: I am not sure if that's a good method. As an example I am writing long comments most of the time, but you can see [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6171/28789) that I am sometimes even explicitly mentioning that I am not suited to helping someone from a content perspective. I can help a bit with formatting and tagging, but that doesn't mean that the draft doesn't need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox is a useful idea, but the problem with it is that it's not clearly linked to anywhere on the main WB site.

We could do with a link in the main menu like this :

[image: Proposed link in main menu]

I don't know if this would require an SE wide change, but we have a WB site theme and perhaps it could be worked into that.

A link like that would help a great deal in directing people towards the Sandbox and giving it a more prominent profile on the site.

Comment: Most sites will lose quite a bit of their individual theme in the next time. What exactly is currenlty open. For example I asked [What will we lose with the redesign?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6045/28789) Adding more buttons (which goes beyond normal theming) is surely something that requires a bigger change. What mods could theoretically do is to add the special mod tag [meta-tag:featured] so that the Sandbox link will appear in the box on the right side. But they would have to regularly renew this.

Comment: Good idea! Some way of making Sandbox linked for ease of access could go a long way to fix this issue.

Comment: Agree, although I would put the link on the other side next to “Ask Question”, and if possible as a smaller/fainter title. Something more grey might help with this