# Is This Question On-Topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I don't really want to make a decision on it, although it it is probably not on topic. What do you think?

> The year is 2055, you are an advanced, self-aware, kind robot who only wants to do good. You were hacked into and forced to kill an entire race, powerless to stop, you blame yourself after.
>
> What would you try to stop killing, and how would you react to the aftermath?
>
> I may as well elaborate on what AIs are:
>
> They are individual units, there is no ultimate overseeing Unit that controls every robot, they are individual, but work together using the Internet.
> There are two processors, one is a Quantum Processor, emulating a true brain/consciousness, the other is a normal computer, and works with the Quantum Processor to control the actual robot. When the normal computer is hacked into to control the robot, the Quantum Processor is unable to do anything but watch.

Answer (score 3):

> What would you try to stop killing, and how would you react to the aftermath?

Smells like plot creation.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would be best off in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), which is specifically for honing questions before asking them; but to answer your question:

I think with some minor rewrites to take out individual references (for example change 'you' to 'a sentient AI robot' this wouldn't be off topic. Presumably the same thing can happen to other robots as well (which falls under the purview of building a world, not focusing on a character).

I will say, however, that the two questions you ask are very much different. It might seem like one is a logical progression of the other, but 'what would you try to stop yourself' and 'how would you feel after' are very different, and would be best off in separate questions.