# What was the problem of this question?

Tags: discussion

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72943/sci-fi-science-physics-of-impossibru-how-the-ball-lightning-destroyed-the-ali

I still don't get, what the mods trying to say.

Comment: I can't edit questions on Meta and there is no way to provide a suggested edit, so I write this as a comment: Please remove the last sentence. It has nothing to do with the discussion. Generally it is important to summarise the discussion so that others can see your point and are up to date on your side of the story. Especially it there is only a long question with a lot of comments and the reference to a discussion in chat people might not want to read this much to get up to date. It looks like you are not putting in any effort and people like to answer if they feel like this.

Comment: But: It is good that you came to Meta and discussed in chat with multiple users. That is the right way to go and I appreciate that you did not just abandon your question!

Answer (score 6):

After a longer discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35832128#35832128) here are some of the points I think you should keep in mind:

- Being funny can be good, but it is really hard to do right. Simple questions tend to be far easier to create / answer.
- Especially big pictures of comic-heads exploding can be quite distracting. **Personally** I prefer just text. Exception: sketches
- Explain concepts people might not be familiar with in a few words and with a link to a source with more details. Generally everyone should be able to understand your question without much previous knowledge and external sources.
- Try to explain everything as concise as possible
- References to games/music/culture in general can be good but not everyone gets them: explain them.
- If you are writing a series refer to the series. Write a link to a list of all the questions of your series in the question so other people interested in the style can find other questions like the one you are asking.
- Use the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). It's a great way to get feedback on the style of the question you have in mind which leads to more views/upvotes/answers and a higher quality of the answers, as well as preventing your question getting closed.
- Generally the easiest way to write a question is as [MichaelK](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35824554#35824554) already mentioned in the comments: **Premise, Problem, Query**. It's the easiest way to structure your question clearly which allows others to understand the question and therefore answer it.
- Listen to people with more experience. MichaelK for example has over 18k rep on WorldBuilding: he knows what he is talking about. Plus the people around here are only trying to help you. We do all of this in our free time.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so after the weekend, there's still no answers to this.

I read it again and it's still fairly confusing as to what you want your readers to answer with.

As has been raised before in [an answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4615/10945) in another of your Meta questions:

> For your second exhibit, this is clearly not a question. There is no hint of a question in the title. The introductory sentence and intro paragraph is not a question, but an explanation of your real purpose to provide an essay. There is a question tacked on the end, as a sort of postscript that does not fit, in a literary manner, with the bulk—it’s an afterthought, asking “how’s that? Brainstorm with me!” because you remembered this is supposed to be a Question venue

My advice: chop out lots of it and keep those parts for future questions.  Stick with one main simple premise.  For example, "How can I weaponize Ball Lightning?".

Also, look at the structure of other questions - most of them are fairly short and clearly contain **Premise, Problem, Query**.

In summary, decide whether you're writing an article or a question (you can't do both) and post it to the relevant place.