# Sci-Fi science: Physics of Impossibru: The series

Tags: discussion, reference

### My name is **NOT** Michio Kaku. This series will explore classic sci-fi tropes, in an attempt to turn them real, thus helping n00bie writers in their quests.

[image]

---

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72943/sci-fi-science-physics-of-impossibru-how-the-ball-lightning-destroyed-the-ali

---

[Sci-fi Science: Physics of Impossibru: "Force fields"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72643/sci-fi-science-physics-of-impossibru-force-fields)

---

Comment: Please remove that comment. It seems inappropriate. If you are having trouble please go to the chat. Sadly I don't know what the problem is. Normally you should be able to provide an answer to your own question. Another way to provide links would be to write them into the question for now if you are starting a series. Maybe someone with more experience can explain why your answers are getting converted to comments.

Comment: All: see [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54794/discussion-between-michaelk-and-redacted-redacted) which came from one of the questions but can be used in-general to discuss the suitability of this series’ post content to the WB SE format.

Comment: I don’t see any *Answers* posted on meta, and no comments either since the profane outburst was deleted.  Comments are not kept in revision control, but answers, even deleted, would still show up for you.  It’s *possible* that some other moderator converted an Answer post to a comment, if it was content more suitable for the latter; but I think there would be a record of that.

Comment: @JDługosz, Redacted: the system automatically converts some link-only answers to comments.  No human took action there.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation I was going to put in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54794/discussion-between-michaelk-and-redacted-redacted) might be better served here.

I general, the format of posting a worked up detailed idea for SF authors is **not a question**.  For your [first exhibit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72643/sci-fi-science-physics-of-impossibru-force-fields), the consensus is that this would best be posted on the associated WB blog.  Even the heavy use of evocative mood-setting images (not strictly needed for illustration) is a good fit there, and not on the Question site.  The Medium blog platform welcomes the kind of banner images you are wanting to incorporate!

For your [second exhibit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72943/sci-fi-science-physics-of-impossibru-how-the-ball-lightning-destroyed-the-ali), this is clearly **not a question**.  There is no hint of a question in the title. The introductory sentence and intro paragraph is not a question, but an explanation of your real purpose to provide an **essay**.  There is a question tacked on the end, as a sort of postscript that does not fit, in a literary manner, with the bulk—it’s an afterthought, asking “how’s that? Brainstorm with me!” because you remembered this is supposed to be a Question venue.

Changing the too-broad postscript to a targeted question “can ball lightning do that really?” is a hack, and does not fit the extended essay you posted and is not your real purpose.  If this was your actual question, you would lead with that and then give just the necessary details.

So in this case too, I submit you are really wanting to **post on the WB *Medium* Blog**, and I assure you this entire series will be **welcome** there in its present form.

Once posted, you can ask questions that **refer** to it.  For example: “Q: can ball lightning be used as a weapon?” and in the body link to the blog posted essay, summarize *just the relevant details* needed for this question, and then restate the Q in a more elaborate form.

Comment: I’m sure the blog welcoming comittee will append a link and more info…

Comment: From the blog welcoming committee: [Want to contribute?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/want-to-contribute-b37191c4362e#.b0xw178ik)