# Is this question about humanity using genetic memory too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Suppose humanity had the ability to access the genetic memories of their maternal line. The lives of ancestors on their mothers side could be open to them with a certain amount of training. The effect would be similar to the animus from assassin's creed, except it would be an innate trait that everyone would be born with. Some would be more skilled in this ability than others. The further back the ancestor, the more difficult it would be to access. The mainstream religion that developed has a strong emphasis on honoring one''s ancestors and an adherence to social traidition.
How can this hypothetical society develop without devolving into cultural and technological stagnation?

Comment: It's good that you ask, but please use the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). It's exactly for discussing if a question will be a good fit for the site.

Comment: I can't edit on Meta, so here are a few hints from my side. First hint: please format your question a bit. Newlines can be very helpful when it comes to readability. Second: you write "maternal line". Does this include males, like the brother of my mother? Third: I never played Assassin's Creed. Please describe in one or two sentences how this works. You can also cite if there is an official reference for this stuff. Typos at "one''s" and "traidition". Your question looks very broad. Please format, post in the Sandbox and ping me. I will have another look and think about it till then.

Comment: See also the Bene Gesserit in Frank Herbert's *Dune* sequence of novels, but this idea didn't get much play in the series. Paul Atreides could access both the paternal and maternal gene line memories as could his sister Alia the Abomination (the female characters tended to be dealt a rough hand).

Comment: Bene Gesserit, anyone?

Comment: For future readers: The question was asked on the Sandbox -> https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4722/28789

Comment: Molot, hit on the head. This is Bene Gesserit to a tee.  There is actually some basis in biology for some sort of ancestral memory inheritence, but people aren't yet sure if it's to do with Mitochondrial DNA/RNA or something else.   One thing for sure though, is that ancestral memory would have to stop at post partum (when the foetus separates from the mother).